# Logstash - Configure global SMTP server

Tags: smtp, logstash

As I understand from docs; Logstash has a default SMTP server setup used by **email output**. By configuration file; particular fields can be changed.

What if I want to configure SMTP setup once; then reuse it in every email output. I could not find any place to set global SMTP settings. When I reviewed the source files; it seems SMTP server settings are hard coded.

Since I have more than a few configuration files; I do not want to repeat SMTP configuration in every email output configuration. Do you have any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available. Suggested method is to use sendmail to relay SMTP. Another alternative is to create a new plugin that reads smtp settings from a smtp configuration file and execute builtin email plugin.